# Java потоки и сокеты

Tags: java, android, сокет

Существует клиент-серверное приложение в работе которого используются сокеты и с каждым сокетом создаётся новый поток, в который передаются некоторые значения. Со временем сервер может принять новые значения, либо должен будет передать их клиенту. Вопрос, каждый ли раз мы должны передавать сокет от клиента к серверу или мы как-то можем приостановить поток до следующего вызова пользователя?

Если нельзя то каким образом мы можем отправить сообщение от сервера к клиенту если это потребуется?

Answer (score 1):

> каждый ли раз мы должны передавать сокет от клиента к серверу или мы
>   как-то можем приостановить поток до следующего вызова пользователя?

Это зависит от задачи. Но, лучше всё-таки по возможности закрывать неактивные соединения и связанные с ними процессы.

> Если нельзя то каким образом мы можем отправить сообщение от сервера к
>   клиенту если это потребуется?

Если соединение открыто, то так и можете отправить через сокет. Как альтернатива, push уведомления.